# Sense for a viscoelastic term of Maxwell type

Tags: thermodynamics, material-science, diffusion, viscosity, rheology

I go reference the book of Jan Prüss (Evolutionary Integral Equations and Applications, 2012) as needed. In this book (pg. 128) it is explored some concepts of stress and strain considering the behaviour of a homogeneous isotropic linear material in simple shearing motion. Summarizing, based on creep and relaxation experiments the relation stress-strain ($\sigma(t)$, resp. $\varepsilon (t)$) considered one is

$$\sigma(t)=(da*\varepsilon')(t) \ \mbox{and} \ \varepsilon(t)=(dk *\sigma)(t)$$

where * is the convolution $da$ is the shear modulos and $dk$ is the creep modulos. Considering $\sigma(t)=e_0(t)$ (the Heavside function), it arrives that $\varepsilon(t)=k(t)$, then expects one that $k(t)$ is a nonnegative, nondecreasing and concave (defined by Prüss as a creep function, pg. Definition 4.4 pg. 94). Other relation (may be relation with the fact of be an isotropic linear material) is that
$$(a*dk)(t)=t, \ t>0$$

After that, it is introduced $a(t)$ and $k(t)$ for some types of materials, for example the Maxwell fluid. Apparently the function $a$ is such that $a'$ represents the Stress relaxation. On page 142 (section 5.6 (i)) we see that the function $a(t)$ is applied in the isotropic fluid equation as the term
$$\int_0^t da(\tau)\Delta u(t-\tau,\tau) d\tau$$

that represents the viscoelastic term in the equation.
I would like some physical meaning (with references, if possible) considering in the expression above $a(t)=e_0(t)+e^{-t}$, i.e. $a'(t)=\delta(t)-e^{-t}$ (we are considering $da(t)=a'(t)dt$). One of the problems is that trying obtain the creep function using the relation
$$(da*k)(t)=t$$
we obtain $k(t)=\frac{t^2}{2}+t$, that is, $k$ is not a concave function. Then I can't use the same situation to give a sense to this situation. I thought that we can obtain meaning with  anisotropic materials, for example if the plate used at experiment of pg. 128 is warm and the material changes your shear modulus with a high temperature, can we expect that the "creep function" let be convex? Does The shear modulus $da=a'(t)dt$ makes sense?
On the other hand, if we substitue $a'$ in the viscoelastic term we have

$$\Delta u(t)-\int_0^t e^{-\tau}\Delta u(t-\tau,x)d\tau$$

and looks like something as the viscoelasticity of a newtonian fluid and a maxwell material. I found some articles with cases as

$$-\Delta u(t)-\int_0^t e^{-\tau}\Delta u(t-\tau,x)d\tau,$$

That is, only with different signal. I need only a physical sense. Thanks any help.

Comment: What's the difference between $da$ and $a$?

Comment: @Chemomechanics $da(t)=a'(t)dt$ make sense into a integral, for example, $\int_0^t g(s)da(s)=\int_0^t g(s) a'(s) ds$ where $a'$ is the derivative of $a$.

Comment: That doesn't tell me what $a$ is. If $da$ is the shear modulus, what is $a$?

Comment: @Chemomechanics By I have understanded, over a physic point of view, $a(t)$ is a function (or distribution) such that $a'(t)$ is the Stress relaxation (see the page 129). Sorry, I dont understand so the physicals concepts, i do mathemathic.